# Rails Custom Validator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord

I have a custom rails validator below that checks whether a new booking is available within the existing bookings based on the start and end date. I'm struggling to figure how I can add a separate 'room' validation. Each booking is for a room, so I want to make sure that the date range is only for the specified room and not for ALL bookings, just the bookings for the individual room. Any thoughts?

```
validates :start_date, :end_date, :presence => true, availability: true
```

```
class AvailabilityValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator

    def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
        bookings = Booking.where(void:'f')
        date_ranges = bookings.map { |b| b.start_date..b.end_date }

        date_ranges.each do |range|
            if range.include? value
                record.errors.add(attribute, "not available")
            end
        end
    end
end
```

EDIT:
Following up on the schema. Fairly simple, all bookings are made by parent associated users ("user_id"), and room is simply another integer attribute within the record (there are 10 rooms).

```
create_table "bookings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "start_date"
    t.datetime "end_date"
    t.boolean "void", default: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.integer "room"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_bookings_on_user_id"
  end
```

Comment: What schema of the data, how do you store rooms? Could you provide examples of expected behaviour?

Comment: Looks like you need to scope your `Booking.where` query but without showing some schema information it's hard to answer definitively

Comment: Added the schema for the bookings table... fairly simple. thanks again!